# Glucose tablets before weightlifting?

Tags: weightlifting, supplements, pre-workout

Before my heavy weight training I take creatine an hour before, and eat a banana 30 minutes before. I am wondering if it would be beneficial to have a glucose tablet right before (or during) the workout.

I usually train for an hour, beginning with compound exercises.

When I do an aerobic exercise, like spin class, I've been told that you only need something other than water if you are training for over an hour (your body doesn't need the extra energy, so it is just adding calories). When running in a marathon, of course we are grateful for the jelly babies and other sweets on the way round :)

Has anybody had success with glucose tablets for weight lifting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the Nick Aldis book "The Superstar Body" he mentions dextrose tablets. He uses them not during a weight-based workout but afterwards. By taking the dextrose tablet with the whey protein shake it helps the body to "reset" and make better use of the protein being ingested.

I have started to take one after my workout, before my protein shake on a weightlifting day. As with these things it is difficult to say "yes! I can see results!" but if it is good enough for a wrestler, it is good enough for me.

As an aside, I will take one between two difficult cardio classes I do to give me an energy boost and I find this beneficial.

Comment: If dextrose is a simple sugar *(like glucose),* how does it help the body make better use of the protein being ingested? I might be wrong, but I don't think you need any energy boost after an exercise *(unless you're in the throes of passing out).* Protein, on the other hand, is necessary.